# How to disable e-mail autolinks in Foswiki?

Tags: wiki, twiki

We are setting up an installation of Foswiki (http://foswiki.org/).

A question to other Foswiki/TWiki users here: is there a way to disable e-mail auto-links in a selected page?

I have figured out that by using `<noautolink>` I can disable automatic wikilinks. It doesn't, however, work for mailto autolinks. So is there a corresponding command for disabling them or does anyone of you know some other workaround?

To be more specific, the problem is that I only need to disable e-mail autolinks, but not other wiki markup conversion. Here is a specific markup example:

> ```
>  * WikiPageName - contact.author@example.com
>  * WikiPageName2 - contact.author2@example.com
>  * WikiPageName3 - contact.author2@example.com
> ```

If I put the whole markup, let's say inside verbatim block, it disables not only e-mail autolinks, but also all other wiki markup, like automatic wikipage linking and listing style.

Use of a plugin to solve this problem can be considered as well, but a pluginless solution is preferred.

Thanks!

Comment: Try scoping <literal/> or <verbatim/> to only appear around addresses. Maybe look for an import plugin that matches your workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for not noticing this earlier.

there *is* a setting in http://foswiki.org/System/DefaultPreferences called NOAUTOLINK that you can set to turn off autolinking.

wrt just Email - yup, harder - monkey patching the core Foswiki::Render::_mailLink might be the most practical.

Sven.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the method I need to change in order to do what I want to do. I wish there was an easier way. However, since this is the way I suppose I'm gonna have to fix it, I'm marking this as the preferred answer. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does `<verbatim />` do what you want?

Comment: No, it doesn't :( With verbatim all Foswiki rendering seems to disappear. What I need is to disable only e-mail autolinks. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try < literal> at the beginning of the link and close it with < / literal>

For instance:
< literal> abc@spamalot.com < / literal>

This can be used in tables as well as in the main body.

Comment: You are absolutely right: literal works, but it doesn't not solve my problem. Please see my re-edited question for details!

Answer (score 0):

You can use !, <nop> or %NOP%, as shown [here](http://foswiki.org/Sandbox/NoAutoLink)

-- Edit for clarification:

Ok, I wasn't clear enough. No, there is no easy solution apart from putting it there, or having a plugin put it there for you (and I don't know of any existing ones doing so). The mailto replacement is done directly inside the rendering engine, so afaict, the only things preventing a mailto are the ones shown on my test page above (which I can't link because serverfault still thinks I'm a spammer, so I'm only allowed 1 link. It's just one link, but...)

The point was... why would you need that? If you write the text, then put the %NOP%. If it comes from a formatted SEARCH, put %NOP% before the formfield. Your example seems to be the result of a SEARCH, so this is easy to fix. Show me your use-case, and maybe I could figure something else out.

Comment: I know ! or %NOP% can be used to disable individual autolinks, but that is not what I'm looking here. Please re-read the question!